# Correct Index of a pin when tapped on pin in map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am developing a map application I wanted to get the index the annotation when tapped on the annotation. I am trying to achieve the same using :

```
    -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

        MKPointAnnotation *point = view.annotation;

        NSLog(@"%@",point.title);

        NSLog(@"%d",indexOfTheObject);
}
```

but it always returns me a random number.

I am assuming that `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate works like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Correct me where I am making mistake.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: iOS and the1pawan solutions will work if you are looking for the index in the array. Are you looking for the annotation's layer index on the `MKMapView` itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    // Annotation is your custom class that holds information about the annotation
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
        Annotation *annot = view.annotation;
        NSInteger index = [self.arrayOfAnnotations indexOfObject:annot];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. `mapView.annotations` is the array you are looking for.

```
  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
            Annotation *annot = view.annotation;
            NSInteger indexOfTheObject = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:annot];
            NSLog(@"%d",indexOfTheObject); 
            NSLog(@"%@",point.title);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

First when loading the pin you need to set the tag of each pin to identify them later.

```
       int count=0;
            for(NSDictionary *dict in self.mapArray)
            {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue], [[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
                [self loadAnnotationWithLocation:coord tag:count];
         count++;
            }

    #pragma mark-map delegates
    -(void)loadAnnotationWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerLocation tag:(NSInteger)annotationTag
    {
        MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:centerLocation];
        ann.ann_tag = annotationTag;
        [self.map addAnnotation:ann];
        [ann release];
        ann=nil;
    }

    -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
    {
        if (view.annotation)
        {
            MyAnnotation *myAnnotation  = (MyAnnotation *)view.annotation;
            if((id <MKAnnotation>)myAnnotation !=self.map.userLocation)
            {
              NSDictionary *dict=[self.mapArray objectAtIndex:myAnnotation.ann_tag];
//do rest of the work here with different pin respect to their tag
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.Let me know if you have any problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];
```

Use this line of code so you can get your current index

Comment: but this include current location also.